# Difference between sub aggregation and nested aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

What are the significant differences between sub aggregation and nested aggregation in elasticsearch?
In which conditions we should use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SUB AGGREGATION

ElasticSearch aggregations run over a set of documents that match a query. If you use a Bucketing aggregation it will split that set of documents into a number of smaller sets. You can place another aggregation inside the bucketing aggregation and it will then run on each of those smaller sets.

For example if you have web access logs that contain a URL and a response time, you could place an average aggregation inside a bucket aggregation to find the average response time per URL.

NESTED AGGREGATION

Although aggregations are 'nested' when doing sub aggregation a 'nested aggregation' usually refers to a particular type of single-bucket aggregation that id for use with nested documents. It allows you to take a set of documents that have collections of sub-documents nested inside them, and run an aggregation across all the sub-documents as if they weren't nested.

For example, if you had a document for each server that had its own access logs embedded within it, you could use an average aggregation inside a nested aggregation to find the average response time across all the servers.

See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html

Comment: Still dont know what's the difference. They are not same?